# Modify spa index.html meta tag with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a react application that I am trying to figure out how to rewrite some meta tags in the static index.html.  I just recently learned that crawlers do not crawl the javascript code and only the html, so I am looking to see if there is a solution via nginx before converting the code base to server side rendering or using prerendering services.  This is my nginx config that I am using to serve the spa.

```
events { }

http{
    server {
        server_name mywebsite.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        server_name www.mywebsite.com;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict";
        
        location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
          expires -1;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          expires 1y;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
        }

        # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

So in this part:

```
# Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Is there a way that I can say hey if the uri contains a specific string... change a meta tag on the index.html that is served to the browser and would this update that static index.html as I would hope for?

Comment: Check out the [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) directive. Unfortunately you cannot use it inside an if block, so you might have to get a bit creative with the `location` directive.

Comment: yup went with your advice on using sub_filter and locations instead of if statements... worked great and much appreciated!